# Apache how make “localhost/<directory>” map to “ C:/Apache/htdocs/<directory>” multiple document root?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

How can i make a directory inside htdocs act as the root directory?

Example:

**Going to** `"localhost/<directory>"`

**Serves** `"C:/Apache/htdocs/<directory>"` as the `"$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']"`

I tried this, it did not change the `"$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']"`

```
<VirtualHost localhost/<directory>:80>
     DocumentRoot C:\Apache\htdocs\<directory>
     ServerName localhost/<directory>
     ServerAlias localhost/<directory>
<Directory "C:\Apache\htdocs\<directory>">
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mixup apache **virtual** directories (like http://servername/directory) and the physical path (like c:\folder)

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80> <-- this is where the apache
                                process listens (just
                                servernames/ips/ports)
     DocumentRoot C:\Apache\htdocs\<directory>
     <-- This path is served in the virtual directory "/"
         (and what you are searching for)

     ServerName localhost
     <-- This is the server's name on which this directive is active

     ServerAlias localhost
     <-- Theese are alternate server's names. NAMEs, no path at all.
</VirtualHost>
```

The  directive doesn't to do anything here, regarding the virtual path; it contains stuff on **how** apache should act in this directory, not where it is.

Comment: But i am still having to remove the <directory> part after localhost via .htaccess, the localhost/<directory> still does not act as the root like localhost/ does.

Comment: The `<directory>` directive can either be in your conf (as above), or placed as a .htaccess file in the path itself. Both would be correct - so you can leave your `<Directory>` in your `<VirtualHost>` element.